# Linux простой вопрос про модули

Tags: linux, kernel

Я пересобрал ядро, чтобы избавиться от бага в одной из версий. Баг ушел, но теперь папка с модулями весит 60 Мб, а раньше весила 7. *Почему это могло произойти, если я собирал практически ту же версию, только патченную с 3.16.6 до 3.16.7 inc-патчем, с практически тем же конфигом (единственно, что, вроде, lguest включил в модули для "посмотреть")?*
Это первый главный вопрос, второй - могу ли я посмотреть, какие модули конкретно в моей системе загружаются постоянно (должен быть где-то их список) и выкинуть все остальные?
Но поскольку это все же субъективное решение а хотелось бы объективное - то все же главнее первый вопрос. Может быть я просто что-то забыл и можно не "выкидывать", а "ограничить что-то".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, я сейчас отвечу на собственный вопрос потому, что получил относящцюся к делу информацию.

1. Речь идет о Tiny Core, модульном "ядерном" дистрибутиве Linux.
2. В ТС модули, не относящиеся к наиболее общим и используемым, вынесены в так называемые "расширения" и могут подгружаться (копироваться) в систему в процессе работы.
3. Соответственно, я действительно могу выкинуть ненужные мне (сравнив список файлов предыдущего init-образа и нового). И, соответственно, все сделано правильно, а причина разницы кроется в особенности дистрибутива.

Answer (score 2):

Ну 60 - это нормально. У меня `/lib/modules/ядро/kernel` весит 125Мб. Вес увеличился из-за того, что вы собрали ядро с вынесением драйверов и еще каких-нть частей ядра в модули или-же собирали все это с включённой отладочной информацией.

Для того, что-бы посмотреть список загруженных модулей выполните в консоли `$ lsmod`. Для управления загружаемыми модулями есть `/etc/modules`, `/etc/modprobe.d` и `/etc/udev`.

Comment: Так у меня Tiny Core. Там ведь ядро вместе с init-образом 10 Мб весит.

Comment: К сожалению про TinyCore ничего не могу подсказать - ни разу не встречался с этим дистрибутивом.

Comment: Да там действительно нужно повыбрасывать ненужные модули, оставив только самые базовые и пересобрать depmod'ом зависимости. Более редкие потом подгружаются в виде отдельных архивов.